# Asynchronously render a WPF visual to a bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, rendertargetbitmap

I saw that the WinRT RenderTargetBitmap is able to render a Visual asynchronously via the "RenderAsync(visual);" method. 
Unfortunately the .net [RendertargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)  does not have a RenderAsync method. 
Is there any workaround or entension for the .net RenderTargetBitmap to allow async rendering of WPF visuals?
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: This is pure guess, have you thought about using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`? [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately this will run also in UI context/thread...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a method to render a visual to bitmap via the BitBlt function. In heavy UIs like in my case this method is 20 times fastern than RenderTargetBitmap.

Here you go.

```
 public static class VisualRender
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    static readonly IntPtr _HwndBottom = new IntPtr(1);
    const UInt32 _SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const UInt32 _SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const UInt32 _SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;


    public static async Task<BitmapSource> RenderAsync(this UIElement uiElement)
    {
        var brush = new VisualBrush(uiElement);
        var topLeft = uiElement.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
        var bottomRight = uiElement.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(uiElement.RenderSize.Width, uiElement.RenderSize.Height));

        var helperWindowLocation = Rect.Empty;
        helperWindowLocation.Union(topLeft);
        helperWindowLocation.Union(bottomRight);

        var width = helperWindowLocation.Width;
        var height = helperWindowLocation.Height;

        //
        var windowsScaleTransform = uiElement.GetWindowsScaleTransform();
        helperWindowLocation.X /= windowsScaleTransform;
        helperWindowLocation.Y /= windowsScaleTransform;
        helperWindowLocation.Width /= windowsScaleTransform;
        helperWindowLocation.Height /= windowsScaleTransform;

        BitmapSource bitmapSourceT = await RenderAsync(brush, helperWindowLocation, new System.Windows.Size(width, height));
        bitmapSourceT.Freeze();
        return bitmapSourceT;
    }

    private static async Task<BitmapSource> RenderAsync(System.Windows.Media.Brush brush, Rect helperWindowLocation, System.Windows.Size snapshotSize)
    {
        // Create a tmp window with its own hwnd to render it later
        var window = new Window { WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None, ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize, ShowInTaskbar = false, Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White };
        window.Left = helperWindowLocation.X;
        window.Top = helperWindowLocation.Y;
        window.Width = helperWindowLocation.Width;
        window.Height = helperWindowLocation.Height;
        window.ShowActivated = false;
        var content = new Grid() { Background = brush };
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(content, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
        window.Content = content;
        var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
        window.Show();
        // Make sure the tmp window is under our mainwindow to hide it
        SetWindowPos(handle, _HwndBottom, 0, 0, 0, 0, _SWP_NOMOVE | _SWP_NOSIZE | _SWP_NOACTIVATE);

        //Wait for the element to render
        //await popupChild.WaitForLoaded();
        await window.WaitForFullyRendered();

        ////Why we have to wait here fore the visualbrush to finish its lazy rendering Process? 
        //// Todo: It seems like very complex uielements does not finish its rendering process within one renderloop
        //// Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851236/rendertargetbitmap-resourced-visualbrush-incomplete-image

        // Async BitBlt the tmp Window
        var bitmapSourceT = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = VisualToBitmapConverter.GetBitmap(handle,
            (int)snapshotSize.Width, (int)snapshotSize.Height);

            var bitmapSource = new SharedBitmapSource(bitmap);
            bitmapSource.Freeze();
            return bitmapSource;
        });
        // Close the Window
        window.Close();

        return bitmapSourceT;
    }

    public static class VisualToBitmapConverter
    {
        private enum TernaryRasterOperations : uint
        {
            SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020,
            SRCPAINT = 0x00EE0086,
            SRCAND = 0x008800C6,
            SRCINVERT = 0x00660046,
            SRCERASE = 0x00440328,
            NOTSRCCOPY = 0x00330008,
            NOTSRCERASE = 0x001100A6,
            MERGECOPY = 0x00C000CA,
            MERGEPAINT = 0x00BB0226,
            PATCOPY = 0x00F00021,
            PATPAINT = 0x00FB0A09,
            PATINVERT = 0x005A0049,
            DSTINVERT = 0x00550009,
            BLACKNESS = 0x00000042,
            WHITENESS = 0x00FF0062,
            CAPTUREBLT = 0x40000000
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, TernaryRasterOperations dwRop);

        public static Bitmap GetBitmap(IntPtr hwnd, int width, int height)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics graphicsFromVisual = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd))
            {
                using (Graphics graphicsFromImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    IntPtr source = graphicsFromVisual.GetHdc();
                    IntPtr destination = graphicsFromImage.GetHdc();

                    BitBlt(destination, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, source, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);

                    graphicsFromVisual.ReleaseHdc(source);
                    graphicsFromImage.ReleaseHdc(destination);
                }
            }

            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static Task WaitForLoaded(this FrameworkElement element)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            element.Loaded -= handler;
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        };
        element.Loaded += handler;
        return tcs.Task;
    }


    public static Task WaitForFullyRendered(this Window window)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        EventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            window.ContentRendered -= handler;
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        };
        window.ContentRendered += handler;
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static double GetWindowsScaleTransform(this Visual visual)
    {
        Matrix m = Matrix.Identity;
        var presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(visual);
        if (presentationSource != null)
        {
            if (presentationSource.CompositionTarget != null) m = presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
        }
        double totalTransform = m.M11;
        return totalTransform;
    }

}
```

The SharedBitmapSource you will find here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841840/690656

Comment: I need to async render huge bitmaps (6000x6000 px). Would this solution work, or is it limited to window size?

Comment: This looks promising. However, I'm not sure about how it is actually used. The method seems not to work if the UIElement to render is not inside the visual tree, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

You can *try* to perform the render on a background thread using something like `await Task.Run(() => bitmap.Render(Button));`, but it's not going to work: the background thread won't be allowed to access the `Button`.

Comment: The only way I see is using reflection to disconnect the element from the dispatcher