# Cancel long running render operation in WPF

Tags: wpf, cancellation, rendertargetbitmap

Is there any way to cancel a possibly long running render operation in WPF?
In my case, I want to render a complex control (in a non-UI-thread) to a bitmap.

```
var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)RenderSize.Width, (int)RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
bitmap.Render(visual);    //May take several seconds, but the result may be obsolete
```

If the size of the target or some other properties change, the bitmap being currently drawn is obsolete - therefore I would like to stop the rendering as fast as possible.

Comment: async/await doesnt help?

Comment: My problem is not that I am waiting for the result but that the operation is very processor intensive, so if I'm starting a new task/thread on every change, these operations will sum up.

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap has no API that supports cancellation, obviously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asynchronously render a WPF visual to a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402011/asynchronously-render-a-wpf-visual-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: Looks promising, but I did not yet get it to work. It throws an InvalidOperationException when trying to render an UIElement that is not in the visual tree ("Not connected to a PresentationSource")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to cancel a possibly long running render operation in WPF?

Short answer: No.

You can't cancel an API that doesn't support cancellation.

A synchronous API such as `RenderTargetBitmap.Render` doesn't return until it has either finished or thrown an exception. You cannot "cancel" it after you have called it I am afraid.

Depending on how and where your bitmap is used, you may consider rendering it on a background thread.

Comment: Ok. I think I will split the rendering into multiple parts and render them individually, if the time gets too long.